# Using \RequirePackage{} in \DeclareOption{}

Tags: packages

I'm trying to make a custom package (named taiga) that works for all my documents by changing the options of the package. For example, for maths documents, I would add `\usepackage[maths]{taiga}` to the permeable. For chemistry documents, I would add `\usepackage[chemistry]{taiga}`.

However, since I cannot `\RequirePackage{}` in `\DeclareOption{}`. I have a really backward way of doing things. Here's an excerpt of taiga.sty

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{maths} 
\setboolean{maths}{false} 

\DeclareOption{maths}{
    \setboolean{maths}{true}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifthenelse{\boolean{maths}}{
    \RequirePackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
    ...
}{}
```

Is this the best way of doing things?

I have come up with a few solutions. The first would be to make separate packages, like `\usepackage{taiga_maths}` or `\usepackage{taiga_chemistry}` but it would be annoying to have to create so many packages. The other option would be to require all packages no matter the options but that would leave me prone to errors or increase the load time.

Comment: Very often you can just delay the code to the end of the package: `\DeclareOption{maths}{\AtEndOfPackage{...}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue; [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468455/240977) provides a solution but is just as backward. The author manually defines a boolean macro, but vbwx's comment points out the `kvoptions` package has `\DeclareBoolOption` for this purpose. In this just as backward way, your excerpt would be slightly cleaner:

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareBoolOption{maths}  % automatically creates \iftaiga@maths switch

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\iftaiga@maths
    \RequirePackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
    ...
\fi
```

I would post this as a comment as it's not much of a satisfying answer but it seems I don't have enough reputation.